# Matrix $B^3 = B-2I$

Tags: matrices

If $B$ is a square matrix and given that $B^3 = B-2I$, find if $B$ is invertible or not.

I tried using determinant on both sides, but got stuck at $\det(B)^3 = \det(B-2I)$.

Comment: $$\det(B)\det(I-B^2) = \det(B-B^3) = \det(2I) = 2^n $$ hence $\det B\neq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Doesn't this imply that $det(I-B^2) ≠ 0$? How is that so?

Comment: Since $2^n\neq 0$, $\det B\neq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio is it ever possible that $det(I−B^2)$ is infinite?

Comment: The entries of a matrix usually are elements of a ring, and the determinant depends on them in a polynomial way. How can it be *infinite*?

Comment: @Larrrrrrrrrry computation of determinant only uses addition, subtraction, and multiplications. If we know that $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we are sure that $\det(B) \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use determinants or anything fancy:

$B^3 = B-2I$ implies $B(I-B^2)=2I$ and so $B^{-1}=\frac12 (I-B^2)$.

This argument works for any polynomial equation $p(B)=0$ when the independent term is not zero.

Comment: thanks, this is easy to understand

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but the former ones (not mine) were also pretty easy to understand *using what you showed* in your question. Of course, maybe you **did like** this one better...

Comment: @DonAntonioPperhaps it is on my lack of understanding of matrices and determinants that I'm not very sure about some of the other answers. I don't find them all as intuitive as this one.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $Bx = 0$. Then

$$
0 = B^3x = Bx - 2x = 2x \implies x = 0
$$

Hence, $B$ is invertible. No determinants needed.

Answer (score 4):

$$2I = B- B^3$$
$$2^n = \det(B)\det(I-B^2)$$

Can you conclude anything?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\;2\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;B\;$ , then $\;2^3=8\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;B^3\;$ , but then, if $\;u\;$ is a corresponding eigenvalue, we get

$$8u=B^3u=(B-2I)u=Bu-2u=2u-2u=0\implies u=0$$

which of course is absurd as $\;u\neq0\;$ (eigenvector!), Thus, $\;2\;$ *cannot be* an eigenvalue of $\;B\iff B-2I\;$ is invertible, and thus

$$\det B^3=(\det B)^3=\det(B-2I)\neq0\implies \det B\neq0\iff B\;\text{is regular}$$

Comment: sorry, i have yet to learn eigenvalue so I don't really understand this :(